# Free tool to create Colour Fonts

Tags: font-design

I am a beginner, and normally use Font Forge and Inkscape to create fonts. But those tools do not support colour fonts yet. Wondering whether there is any free tool for Windows or Ubuntu that can help me create colour fonts.

I know there are a few paid tools. But I am currently learning and not doing anything commercially.

Update 1:

Installed OpenType SVG Editor in Windows 10. Was able to use my colourful SVG and build an OTF and TTF file. Sadly, Windows says it is not a font file that can be installed.

Comment: Hi. I found this [Open Type SVG font editor](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/opentype-svg-font-editor/9NJ7K9JX60P1?hl=en-gb&gl=gb&rtc=1) I've never used it, so can't vouch for it. But it says you can use it to embed SVGs into an existing Open Type Font. Although Inkscape doesn't support display of colour fonts itself, you could still use it to create the SVGs needed to use in the Microsoft app.  Note: I have no affiliation with Microsoft or the developer of the app.

Comment: The github link: https://github.com/microsoft/OpenType-SVG-Font-Editor

Comment: Thanks, I will try and update.